# c# -> WPF -> Alt+Shortcut works, Shortcut on its own works, Alt followed by shortcut does not

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, shortcut, alt

In `c# applications using WPF`, including a very simple one with 1 button,
I have several shortcut keys.  They all behave in the following manner

`Alt+Shortcut` key pressed at the same time works, Shortcut key on its own works (not what I was expecting without showing the underscore unless it is shown already). Alt followed by short cut key goes beep and does not work, presumably reporting some error.

What is going on here?  How can I get consistent behaviour.  In WinForms it used to be just `Alt+Shortkey` that worked.  That is what I would like unless the standard behaviour has changed.

thanks

Comment: please post some code and more explanation. As far as I know key combinations should never been considered as **should be pressed at the same time**. User can always press them easily (press modifier key first and then the shortcut key).

Comment: Alt alone just turn the shortcut underline on and off.  The only way to execute the shortcut is Alt +

Answer (score 1):

But that is how it works
Alt + key is how you execute the short cut
Alt alone just turns the shortcut indicator on and off